# Mac OSX shell will not change

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh

I'm trying to get ZSH as my default shell, I've installed using the installer from the *oh-my-zsh* project and it all installs fine, but I cannot change it to be the default shell:

When I `echo $SHELL` it gives "`/bin/zsh`",

- However `ps -p $$`  seems to suggest `bash` (although I have seen this suggest `zsh` even when it isn't)
- I've also tried changing it in the *Accounts → Advanced settings → Startup shell* and in the Terminal preferences.
- Using `chsh -s /bin/zsh` says "No changes made..." i.e. it also thinks `zsh` is in use.

I can switch to zsh manually by typing `zsh` or `/bin/zsh`, just can't change it to default and that is rather annoying.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `echo bash=${BASH_VERSION:-not running}, zsh=${ZSH_VERSION:-not running}` to find out for sure what you're running.

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you running? What does `id -P` report at the end of the line? Did you really install `zsh` at `/bin/zsh`? Any chance you have something in a shell startup file that invokes bash? And, sorry to ask this, but did you know that changing your default shell will NOT automatically take effect in already-open Terminal windows?

Comment: Spiff, yes the computer had been restarted multiple times, and the end of that line was regarding screen sharing... Thanks for your response though!

Comment: It could be that you hadn't installed git when you ran the oh-my-zsh installation script. The error message is inconspicuous - in comparison to the flashy "oh my zsh is now installed" which you get even if it wasn't. That lion comes with zsh installed just added to the confusion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange guys, but I installed some software updates and after that restart (the computer had already been restarted multiple times) it just worked...

Very odd but at least there was nothing actually going wrong...

Thanks to everyone who responded!

Comment: Please mark this answer accepted once it's possible, so the system can consider this question answered.

Answer (score 1):

Worth pointing out that you have to actually add whatever new shell you've put in that isn't there on a vanilla box to the /etc/shells file (or somesuch similar)... You didn't post the whole text from your **chsh** attempt, and the snippet you *did* put down at least leaves that door open.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response! That was all I was getting from the chsh, its had been solved now anyway, I shall post the answer now.